# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range Exception - dispatchTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-view

I have this method in my custom view which extends `FrameLayout`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int currentItem = vp.getCurrentItem();
    if (inDragPanelZone(currentItem, ev.getX(), ev.getY()) && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {      
        if (!shouldAllowPaging()) { 
            return true; 
        }
        vp.setPagingEnabled(true);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Once in a while - I'm getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1995)
at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:86)
at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:210)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1734)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5710)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
at MyView.dispatchTouchEvent(DraggablePane.java:176)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1918)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1377)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2391)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1866)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5890)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3077)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2619)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:983)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2628)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also tried using `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and got the same exception.

**Here is an additional stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
    at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:2013)
    at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
    at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:86)
    at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:210)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1734)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5724)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1725)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1739)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2071)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2426)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2019)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5904)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3155)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2670)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1014)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same problems sometimes. Try to dispatch copy of `ev` instead of original `MotionEvent`. In the very begginning of method add something like `MotionEvent evCopy = MotionEvent.obtain(ev)` and call `super.dispatchTouchEvent(evCopy)` instead.

Comment: Did it resolved the issue completely for you?

Comment: I didn't tried it yet. For me, problem disappeared when I get rid of `ScrollView` and redesigned the app for another reasons.

Comment: That doesn't work, thanks anyway @Dmitry Zaitsev

Comment: it's `return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);` in the code snippet in the question.

Comment: Does this still happen in the lastest versions of support v4?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a bug in 2.1 (Eclair) where the pointer index isn't checked and is sometimes -1. You can create a custom view that extends ViewPager, override onTouchEvent and wrap the call to super.onTouchEvent in a try/catch. Whilst not a very pretty fix, I remember that it has no side effects (like missed touch events).

Comment: I saw this bug, and I've used the workaround you suggested before, but I'm trying to find a way to handle it properly..

Comment: There was an update to the support library recently which may have fixed this error (as in, they fixed ViewPager, not the causing bug in 2.1). Haven't checked it out.

Comment: @FunkTheMonk nope the bug is still there :(

Comment: I've still got this bug, but the suggested fix works

Comment: Did anyone see the same behaviour in android 4.4.4? I see a stacktrace where `at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.c(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)` is in front of `at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:2227)` and it results in the above mentioned exception...

Comment: @prom85 I answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670970/viewpager-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-pointerindex-out-of-range/31459946#31459946

Answer (score 15):

Adding to the above answer Also you can try Overriding onInterceptTouchEvent method and surround super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) with try and catch worked for me in a ViewPager

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What should i do if it got crash inside super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I created a custom ViewPager to catch the exception. Here is the solution in `kotlin`:

```
class CustomViewPager : ViewPager {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean =
        try {
            super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            //uncomment if you really want to see these errors
            //e.printStackTrace();
            false
        }
}
```