# pointerIndex out of range in Android ScrollView

Tags: android

I have searched for the solution on stackoverflow but there is no scenario matching mine. I have a textview wrapped by scrollview:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titlefav" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have a gesture detector for onfling and have bound this listener to both textview as well scrollview:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    final String TAG = MyGestureDetector.class.getSimpleName();

    // for touch left or touch right events
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 40; // default is 120
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 600;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                onHorizonTouch(true); // left
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                onHorizonTouch(false); // right
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
tv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
sv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Now when the user is either trying to touch or swipe (I am not sure), I see following exception in Google Play with no mention of MainActivity. Any idea how can I resolve this issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:2090)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:839)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7337)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2145)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2115)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1468)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4503)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new MyGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
getView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector != null) 
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used above code and published new version of my app but still users see the exception. On my 4.0.2 android, it works fine. The crash report on google play displays device as "Other"

Comment: @Sandeep edited answer, I think I had misread some of the code initially.

Comment: sorry for delayed reply. What is this method getView(). I see compiler error when using this in onCreate of activity.

Comment: get view() is used for fragments to identify the layout view.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue and solved it using the method in the answer to this question:

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range Exception - dispatchTouchEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459196/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-pointerindex-out-of-range-exception-dispat)

Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me was to comment out the onDown(MotionEvent e) method

```
/*
@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
}
*/
```